# Access all fields of an SQLite query record result?

Tags: qt, sqlite

I'm learning `Sqlite` in Qt but have run into a problem accessing record values returned by a `QSqlQuery`.

The details are below but the gist is: I get a `QSqlRecord` back from a query and want to access all fields of the record but `QSqlRecord.count` is reporting only one column when there clearly are two (in the example they are *id* and *keyword*).

Am I misunderstanding SQLite and what a query does, or is this a problem with how I am trying to access the records?

---

**This is my schema:**

[image]

**This is my test data:**

[image]

**Full code:**

```
void MainWindow::on_addKeywordBtn_clicked()
{

    // find a matching keyword
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.prepare("SELECT keyword FROM keywords WHERE keyword = ?");
    query.addBindValue(QString("blue"));
    query.exec();


    while (query.next()) {
        QString k = query.value(0).toString();
        qDebug() << "found" << k;

        QSqlRecord rec = query.record();

        qDebug() << "Number of columns: " << rec.count();

        int idIndex = rec.indexOf("id");
        int keywordIndex = rec.indexOf("keyword");
         qDebug() << query.value(idIndex).toString() << query.value(keywordIndex).toString();

    }
}
```

Console output:

```
found "blue" 
Number of columns:  1 
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
"" "blue"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line, actually query

```
  query.prepare("SELECT keyword FROM keywords WHERE keyword = ?");
```

in your code you explicitly instruct database to return you only one column, proper solutions would be:

```
  query.prepare("SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyword = ?");
```

or

```
   query.prepare("SELECT id, keyword FROM keywords WHERE keyword = ?");
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I was wrongly thinking that I would get an object (record) back containing all values.